# How can i remove the 2nd auth screen after clicking on the one tap sign in?

Tags: javascript, google-identity, google-my-business-api

I am trying to create a platform using google my business API and i am using google one-tap sign in for taking the consent of the users but when i am using this code then there is another auth screen is popup when I click on the one tap sign in here is the image example
[one tap sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHnyH.png)

[2nd screen after one tap sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2FkH.png)
i want to remove the 2nd screen and proceed with gmb consent

```
 <script>
      window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id:
            "8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          callback: handleCredentialResponse,
        });
        google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
          if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
            console.log("opted out");
          }
        });
        function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
          // window.location = "https://github.com/";
          const config = {
            response_type: "permission",
            scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage",
            client_id:
              "8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          };
          gapi.auth2.authorize(config, function (response) {
            
          });
        }
      };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The second auth screen is actually a pop-up window, which is useful to prevent clickjacking.

1. On non-Chrome (or Chrome 74 or before) browsers, the pop-up window is required, since they doesn't have a trustable way to prevent clickjacking attcks.
   More details at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/features#dialog-to-prevent-unintended-clicks
2. On Chrome 75+, the pop-up window is uncessary, unless the One Tap UI is covered by other content.
   More details at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/display-google-one-tap#do_not_cover_google_one_tap

Comment: so according to your answer, i am doing fine there is no problem to have an extra popup?

Comment: The drop off rate would be much higher with the extra popup. So, if possible, try to remove it.